# Connecting to SMB without adding a second user on windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, samba, windows-10-v21h2

I have created SMB share on my windows 10 PC. Now I want to connect to that network from my android mobile phone. Both my devices are connected to a router. The problem is I can't use my admin credentials to connect to that network. I have to add a second user to my PC and use that credentials to connect. Is there any way to bypass that? I am not interested on creating multiple user account on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the admin credentials? There is no such limitation. Make sure that you have the correct username (if you are using a Microsoft account it may be different than what you see on the lock screen), and the correct password (again not the PIN from the lock screen).

Check your username by running `whoami`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am using my Microsoft account. In username and password, I'm using my email address and password that I use to login to my Microsoft account. So, I hope everything is correct. I have also added permission on security, sharing settings. Still not working.